# Keycloak OIDC Filter redirect_uri is always http

Tags: keycloak, wicket-6

My application was developed using wicket and integrated with keycloak 10.0.2.

I have an issue with the redirect_uri, it is always in `http` (like `https://id.dev.subok.com/auth/realms/subok/protocol/openid-connect/auth? ... &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.subok.com%2F ...`.

To elaborate:
When I try to access my app via `https://test.subok.com`, I am expecting that the `redirect_uri` will be `https%3A%2F%2Ftest.subok.com%2F` but it was `http%3A%2F%2Ftest.subok.com%2F`. The `redirect_uri` is always `http` even if I use `http` or `https`.

The way I integrate Keycloak to my application is via servlet filter:

**POM**

```
...

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-servlet-filter-adapter</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-authz-client</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.2</version>
</dependency>

...
```

**web.xml**

```
...

<filter>
  <filter-name>keycloak</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>keycloak.config.skipPattern</param-name>
    <param-value>/((error-page.html)|(access-denied-page.html))</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>keycloak</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

...
```

Is there a way to override the value of generated `redirect_uri`? Specifically to use `https` if the request is `https` and `http` if the request is `http`. Or just use `https` redirect_url for both http and https request?